# Troubleshooting unmatched foreign keys in mysql tables

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I have two myIsam tables `student` and `fee` which were later changed into InnoDB engine and assigned foreign key to `section` field in `fee` table which points to `section` field in `student` table with UPDATE and DELETE CASCADE. My problem is that the existing `section` field values does not match with the existing `student` section values. This happened because before I had changed my engine, I had updated student table `section` field, and thought that `section` field values in `fee` table would also changed when I converted both the tables and assigned foreign keys to `section` field in both the tables. I am not sure whether synchronization will solve it. I am newbie and have no idea how I would solve this. Please help me.

Fee table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `fee` (
  `f_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `regd` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Class` varchar(20) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `Section` varchar(10) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `Amount` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Balance` int(11) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`f_id`),
   KEY `Section` (`Section`),
  KEY `Rollno` (`Rollno`),
  KEY `regd` (`regd`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci 
 AUTO_INCREMENT=2500;

ALTER TABLE `fee`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fee_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`Section`) 
  REFERENCES `student` (`Section`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fee_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`Rollno`) 
  REFERENCES `student` (`Roll_no`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Student Table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `student` (
  `regd` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `Date_of_birth` date NOT NULL,
  `Sex` varchar(20) COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL,
  `Roll_no` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Section` varchar(20) COLLATE latin1_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`regd`),
  KEY `Section` (`Section`),
  KEY `Roll_no` (`Roll_no`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci 
 AUTO_INCREMENT=2500;
```

Comment: Thanks for providing the tables, that all looks fine, but it won't help you rematch the data.

Comment: @Arth, so what would be the best option to rematch? Do you think synchronizing will help? I need to know because I don't want to smash my table.

Comment: See my answer, I'm not sure what you mean by synchronizing, but you need to update each of your `fee` records to point to the correct `student`.. where you get the data to do that, or if you have the data at all is not provided in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have some record of which fee should point to which student, I'm afraid you can't do this.

You'll have to recreate the links; either using logs of which `UPDATE`s you ran, from a backup or manually.

Comment: Update statement, I have already run it but did not work. By Manual, it works but there are more than two thousand rows in the table. For new row it works fine.

Comment: "My problem is that the existing section field values does not match with the existing student section values." This was what I was talking about, what `UPDATE` statement are you referring to that didn't work? And what does didn't work mean? Your question has now become very vague.

Comment: sorry for my english. I will update my question with my two tables.